# Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function when parsing JSONP response in jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jsonp

I am trying to grab data from a wordpress blog using the WP-API plugin. My js file is using jQuery to make ajax calls to the api. I need to use JSONP as the response type since I am trying to access cross domain information.

When the page loads, I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function" and my response begins like this: `/**/1([{"ID":231,"title":blahblahblah...` with the error pointing at the "1" in the console.

This is the code I am using to try and grab the data and parse it:

```
function get_posts(num_offset) {
        offset = num_offset,
        url = 'http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=1&filter[posts_per_page]=5&filter[offset]=' + offset;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                consol.log(data);
                console.log(url);
            }
        });

        // second ajax call to get the total number of posts
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: 'http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=1&filter[offset]=-1',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });


    }
```

I guess I need to know how I can remove the "Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function" error and then how I would be able to parse the JSONP data.

much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the other end that your callback's name is `1`, in your URL:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=1&filter[offset]=-1
Here --------------------------------^^^^^^
```

You want to use the name of the callback function you have on your page that you're expecting to receive the JSONP response, which needs to be a validate identifier literal (so not `1`).

Because you're using jQuery, it's best by far if you let jQuery worry about what the callback name should be, by leaving off that query parameter entirely and letting jQuery add it. Since `_jsonp` is an unusual query string parameter name for this, you'll need to tell jQuery what the parameter name is.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?&filter[offset]=-1',
    // No _jsonp=1 here ------------------------^
    jsonp: '_jsonp',
    // ^^ new parameter here
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually that _jsonp parameter is used by the WP-API pulgin to change the server MIME type to application/json. as this is the code snippent in the plugin:

`$content_type = isset( $_GET['_jsonp'] ) ? 'application/javascript' : 'application/json';`

Comment: @Narutkowski: I hope not, that's the wrong mime type for JSONP (it's the JSON mime type; the correct mime type to serve JSONP with is `application/javascript` because it's actually a JavaScript file). I suspect it's what the endpoint uses to know that it should return JSONP, **and** that it tells the endpoint what callback name to use. So if you try the above, I suspect it will correct the problem.

Comment: @Narutkowski: Right, it's using it to set `application/javascript` if it's going to return JSONP. But I suspect if you look later, you'll find that it's **also** using the query parameter to decide what function name to use in the JSONP response. E.g., it's both a flag (ah, we should return JSONP) **and** the name of the callback (and that's the name we should use for the callback).

Comment: That is in the code, however now it is working without the parameter and return the jsonp. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Narutkowski: Yeah, I read that code backward, see my replacement comment (posted just *seconds* before yours) above. Glad that helped!

Comment: Ah that must be why it is working. Before when I did not have the jsonp set at all it was throwing the MIME type error. Again thanks!